# Find the row number using the first element of the row

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` matrix where I store some kind of key in the first element of the each row (or in another way all keys are in the first column).

```
[[123,0,1,1,2],
[12,1,2,3,4],
[1,0,2,5,4],
[90,1,1,4,3]]
```

I want to get the row number searching by the key. I found that we can use `numpy.where` for this but not clear how to employ it to get the row number. I want something like

```
>>numpy.func(myMatrix,90)
3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a key and some data, you really should be using a dictionary, not a list. Finding items in a dict by key is fast, searching through a list is slowwwww.

Comment: _Row_ number (noun, refers to the position of the row, the _'line'_ of your matrix) and _raw_ (adjective, means _wild, brute_ or _unedited, unprocessed_) number are different. The latter perhaps isn't even a valid term. I suppose you're talking about _row_ number here.

Comment: Why not use a pandas DataFrame? Your column of keys would be the index and there are many ways from there to select, group, and subset your data.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [online doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where), `numpy.where` if you give it only a boolean array will return lists of coordinates (one list per dimension) for the elements that are `True`.
So we can get the information you want by grabbing the first column of your array , comparing it with the element you want to find and calling np.where on that boolean array. All that would look like that:

```
row,column=np.where(myMatrix[;,0]==90) 
#Note that column will just be 0 here
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the first column with `90` within `np.where`. It will return an array of the indices of items which are equal with `90`:

```
In [3]: A = np.array([[123,0,1,1,2],
[12,1,2,3,4],
[1,0,2,5,4],
[90,1,1,4,3]])


In [6]: np.where(A[:,0]==90)[0]
Out[6]: array([3])
```